# Random Projections and separability

Tags: clustering

I am new to machine learning and I am considering the following problem:

Suppose you have clusters of points in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $N$ large. The Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma specifies how distances between points are preserved when reducing dimensionality. But what if I don't care about distances and I am only interested in keeping the clusters separate when projecting to one single dimension. Which condition should hold on the clusters for a random projections from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}$ to be able to avoid the points in the cluster to overlap? Is there a result defining these conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Define cluster separation.

Let's say the average distance of points in a cluster is $a$, and the average distance of points in different clusters in $b$ with $a\ll b$.
Then a random projection with the Johnson-Lindenstrauss properties should preserve this difference with high probability, shouldn't it?

Most distance-based definitions of cluster separation should be fine.

You probably can even use minimum between two clusters and maximum inside a cluster.